# what will be the best http return result type and can return HttpResponseMessage in single line of code statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core web api and I need to execute one task `OneTask` and on successful execution of  `OneTask` it should return OK staus otherwise error response. I want `HttpResponseMessage` and can something return `return Ok(awit OneTask());`

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<OkObjectResult> Post()
    {
        await OneTask;
        return Ok(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));
    }


public async Task OneTask()
    {
        await //some task
    }
```

Comment: How do you check if `OneTask` execution succeeded?

Comment: this is something I also not sure?

Comment: How the OneTask decides if it is successful or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IActionResult<T>` interface is the best practice to respond to the client.

So change the code like this :

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("PostWithValue")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostWithValue()
{
    var result = await OneTaskWithReturnValue();

    return Ok(result);
}
public async Task<bool> OneTaskWithReturnValue()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);

    return true;
}
```

Also, beware of `async void (Task without <T>)` that is a bad idea because you have problem with handling exceptions  :

In a nutshell:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("PostWithValue")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostWithValue()
{
    var result = await OneTaskWithReturnValue();

    if (!result)
    {
        return BadRequest("Message for Error");
    }

    return Ok("Message for OK Status");
}
public async Task<bool> OneTaskWithReturnValue()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);

    // Do you task

    return true;
}
```